# Configuring webSphere 8 with atmosphere

Tags: websphere, atmosphere

I need to implement something similar to chat function. I am intending to upgrade to Primefaces 5.1. Currently, I am using websphere 8.0.0.6. If I am not wrong, it cannot support websocket for websphere 8.0.0.6. Which atmosphere should I use? Runtime or native?

**Error**

```
[10/16/15 14:33:20:618 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72244 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Atmosphere LifeCycle with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
[10/16/15 14:33:20:620 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72246 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installed AtmosphereInterceptor  Track Message Size Interceptor using | with priority BEFORE_DEFAULT 
[10/16/15 14:33:20:627 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72253 [WebContainer : 0] WARN org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils - META-INF/services/org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework not found in class loader
[10/16/15 14:33:20:659 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72285 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Atmosphere is using org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor for processing annotation
[10/16/15 14:33:20:660 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72286 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor - AnnotationProcessor class org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor$ServletContainerInitializerAnnotationProcessor being used
[10/16/15 14:33:20:662 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72288 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.MeteorService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Documented
[10/16/15 14:33:20:662 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72288 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.BroadcasterCacheListenerService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Documented
[10/16/15 14:33:20:662 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72288 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.WebSocketProcessorService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Documented
[10/16/15 14:33:20:662 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72288 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.AtmosphereInterceptorService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Documented
[10/16/15 14:33:20:662 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72288 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.AsyncSupportListenerService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Documented
[10/16/15 14:33:20:662 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72288 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.ManagedService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Documented
[10/16/15 14:33:20:662 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72288 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.AtmosphereHandlerService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Documented
[10/16/15 14:33:20:662 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72288 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.WebSocketHandlerService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Documented
[10/16/15 14:33:20:662 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72288 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.BroadcasterFactoryService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Documented
[10/16/15 14:33:20:662 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72288 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.BroadcasterCacheInspectorService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Documented
[10/16/15 14:33:20:662 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72288 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.EndpointMapperService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Documented
[10/16/15 14:33:20:663 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72288 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Documented
[10/16/15 14:33:20:663 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72289 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.BroadcasterFilterService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Documented
[10/16/15 14:33:20:663 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72289 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.BroadcasterListenerService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Documented
[10/16/15 14:33:20:663 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72289 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.BroadcasterService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Documented
[10/16/15 14:33:20:663 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72289 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.AsyncSupportService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Documented
[10/16/15 14:33:20:663 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72289 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.WebSocketProtocolService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Documented
[10/16/15 14:33:20:663 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72289 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.BroadcasterCacheService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Documented
[10/16/15 14:33:20:663 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72289 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in class org.atmosphere.annotation.AtmosphereServiceProcessor being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation
[10/16/15 14:33:20:663 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72289 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in class org.atmosphere.annotation.BroadcasterFactoryServiceProcessor being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation
[10/16/15 14:33:20:663 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72289 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in class org.atmosphere.annotation.BroadcasterCacheListenererviceProcessor being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation
[10/16/15 14:33:20:663 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72289 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in class org.atmosphere.annotation.BroadcasterCacheServiceProcessor being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation
[10/16/15 14:33:20:663 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72289 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in class org.atmosphere.annotation.WebSocketProcessorServiceProcessor being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation
[10/16/15 14:33:20:663 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72289 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in class org.atmosphere.annotation.BroadcasterCacheInspectorServiceProcessor being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation
[10/16/15 14:33:20:664 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72289 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in class org.atmosphere.annotation.WebSocketHandlerServiceProcessor being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation
[10/16/15 14:33:20:664 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72290 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in class org.atmosphere.annotation.MeteorServiceProcessor being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation
[10/16/15 14:33:20:664 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72290 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in class org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointProcessor being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation
[10/16/15 14:33:20:664 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72290 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in class org.atmosphere.annotation.BroadcasterServiceProcessor being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation
[10/16/15 14:33:20:664 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72290 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in class org.atmosphere.annotation.AsyncSupportServiceProcessor being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation
[10/16/15 14:33:20:664 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72290 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in class org.atmosphere.annotation.AtmosphereHandlerServiceProcessor being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation
[10/16/15 14:33:20:664 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72290 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in class org.atmosphere.annotation.ManagedServiceProcessor being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation
[10/16/15 14:33:20:664 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72290 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in class org.atmosphere.annotation.BroadcasterListenerServiceProcessor being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation
[10/16/15 14:33:20:664 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72290 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in class org.atmosphere.annotation.AsyncSupportListenerServiceProcessor being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation
[10/16/15 14:33:20:664 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72290 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in class org.atmosphere.annotation.AtmosphereInterceptorServiceProcessor being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation
[10/16/15 14:33:20:664 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72290 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in class org.atmosphere.annotation.EndpointMapperServiceProcessor being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation
[10/16/15 14:33:20:664 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72290 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in class org.atmosphere.annotation.BroadcastFilterServiceProcessor being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation
[10/16/15 14:33:20:664 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72290 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in class org.atmosphere.annotation.WebSocketProtocolServiceProcessor being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation
[10/16/15 14:33:20:664 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72290 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.MeteorService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Retention
[10/16/15 14:33:20:664 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72290 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.BroadcasterCacheListenerService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Retention
[10/16/15 14:33:20:665 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72290 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.WebSocketProcessorService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Retention
[10/16/15 14:33:20:665 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72291 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.AtmosphereInterceptorService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Retention
[10/16/15 14:33:20:665 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72291 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.AtmosphereService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Retention
[10/16/15 14:33:20:665 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72291 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.AsyncSupportListenerService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Retention
[10/16/15 14:33:20:665 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72291 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.ManagedService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Retention
[10/16/15 14:33:20:665 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72291 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.AtmosphereHandlerService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Retention
[10/16/15 14:33:20:665 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72291 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.WebSocketHandlerService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Retention
[10/16/15 14:33:20:665 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72291 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.BroadcasterFactoryService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Retention
[10/16/15 14:33:20:665 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72291 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.BroadcasterCacheInspectorService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Retention
[10/16/15 14:33:20:665 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72291 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.EndpointMapperService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Retention
[10/16/15 14:33:20:665 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72291 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Retention
[10/16/15 14:33:20:665 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72291 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.BroadcasterFilterService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Retention
[10/16/15 14:33:20:665 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72291 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.BroadcasterService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Retention
[10/16/15 14:33:20:665 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72291 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.BroadcasterListenerService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Retention
[10/16/15 14:33:20:665 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72291 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.AsyncSupportService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Retention
[10/16/15 14:33:20:666 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72292 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.WebSocketProtocolService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Retention
[10/16/15 14:33:20:666 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72292 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.BroadcasterCacheService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Retention
[10/16/15 14:33:20:666 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72292 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in class org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointInterceptor being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.service.AtmosphereInterceptorService
[10/16/15 14:33:20:667 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72293 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.MeteorService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Target
[10/16/15 14:33:20:667 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72293 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.BroadcasterCacheListenerService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Target
[10/16/15 14:33:20:667 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72293 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.WebSocketProcessorService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Target
[10/16/15 14:33:20:667 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72293 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.AtmosphereInterceptorService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Target
[10/16/15 14:33:20:668 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72294 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.AtmosphereService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Target
[10/16/15 14:33:20:668 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72294 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.AsyncSupportListenerService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Target
[10/16/15 14:33:20:668 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72294 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.ManagedService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Target
[10/16/15 14:33:20:668 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72294 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.AtmosphereHandlerService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Target
[10/16/15 14:33:20:668 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72294 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.WebSocketHandlerService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Target
[10/16/15 14:33:20:668 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72294 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.BroadcasterFactoryService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Target
[10/16/15 14:33:20:668 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72294 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.BroadcasterCacheInspectorService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Target
[10/16/15 14:33:20:668 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72294 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.EndpointMapperService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Target
[10/16/15 14:33:20:668 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72294 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.AtmosphereAnnotation being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Target
[10/16/15 14:33:20:668 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72294 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.BroadcasterFilterService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Target
[10/16/15 14:33:20:669 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72295 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.BroadcasterService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Target
[10/16/15 14:33:20:669 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72295 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.BroadcasterListenerService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Target
[10/16/15 14:33:20:669 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72295 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.AsyncSupportService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Target
[10/16/15 14:33:20:669 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72295 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.WebSocketProtocolService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Target
[10/16/15 14:33:20:669 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72295 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in interface org.atmosphere.config.service.BroadcasterCacheService being scanned: interface java.lang.annotation.Target
[10/16/15 14:33:20:669 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72295 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in class org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointMapper being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.service.EndpointMapperService
[10/16/15 14:33:20:821 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72447 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AnnotationHandler - Found Annotation in class org.primefaces.showcase.push.chat.ChatResource being scanned: interface org.primefaces.push.annotation.PushEndpoint
[10/16/15 14:33:20:900 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72526 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installed AtmosphereHandler org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointHandlerProxy mapped to context-path /{room}/{user} and Broadcaster Class org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster
[10/16/15 14:33:20:900 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 72526 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installed AtmosphereInterceptor [@PushEndpoint Interceptor] mapped to AtmosphereHandler org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointHandlerProxy
[10/16/15 14:33:22:541 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74167 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Auto detecting WebSocketHandler in /WEB-INF/classes/
[10/16/15 14:33:23:030 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74656 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installed WebSocketProtocol org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol 
[10/16/15 14:33:23:042 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74668 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installing Default AtmosphereInterceptor
[10/16/15 14:33:23:043 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74669 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -     org.atmosphere.interceptor.CorsInterceptor : CORS Interceptor Support
[10/16/15 14:33:23:043 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74669 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -     org.atmosphere.interceptor.CacheHeadersInterceptor : Default Response's Headers Interceptor
[10/16/15 14:33:23:043 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74669 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -     org.atmosphere.interceptor.PaddingAtmosphereInterceptor : Browser Padding Interceptor Support
[10/16/15 14:33:23:044 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74670 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -     org.atmosphere.interceptor.AndroidAtmosphereInterceptor : Android Interceptor Support
[10/16/15 14:33:23:044 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74670 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -     org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor : Heartbeat Interceptor Support
[10/16/15 14:33:23:045 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74671 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -     org.atmosphere.interceptor.SSEAtmosphereInterceptor : SSE Interceptor Support
[10/16/15 14:33:23:045 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74671 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -     org.atmosphere.interceptor.JSONPAtmosphereInterceptor : JSONP Interceptor Support
[10/16/15 14:33:23:046 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74672 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -     org.atmosphere.interceptor.JavaScriptProtocol : Atmosphere JavaScript Protocol
[10/16/15 14:33:23:046 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74672 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -     org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor
[10/16/15 14:33:23:046 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74672 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -     org.atmosphere.interceptor.OnDisconnectInterceptor : Browser disconnection detection
[10/16/15 14:33:23:046 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74672 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -     org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor
[10/16/15 14:33:23:046 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74672 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installed AtmosphereInterceptor  Track Message Size Interceptor using | with priority BEFORE_DEFAULT 
[10/16/15 14:33:23:046 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74672 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Atmosphere LifeCycle with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
[10/16/15 14:33:23:046 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74672 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Set org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor.disableDefaults to disable them.
[10/16/15 14:33:23:048 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74674 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Using EndpointMapper class org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointMapper
[10/16/15 14:33:23:048 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74674 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Using BroadcasterCache: org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache
[10/16/15 14:33:23:048 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74674 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Default Broadcaster Class: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster
[10/16/15 14:33:23:054 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74680 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Broadcaster Polling Wait Time 100
[10/16/15 14:33:23:054 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74680 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Shared ExecutorService supported: true
[10/16/15 14:33:23:062 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74688 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Messaging Thread Pool Size: Unlimited
[10/16/15 14:33:23:062 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74688 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Async I/O Thread Pool Size: 200
[10/16/15 14:33:23:062 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74688 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Using BroadcasterFactory: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcasterFactory
[10/16/15 14:33:23:062 SGT] 00000015 SystemErr     R 74688 [WebContainer : 0] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Using WebSocketProcessor: org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor
```

Comment: What did you try? What happened?

Comment: @Kukeltje I tried primefaces 5.1 with atmosphere runtime 2.2.2. But there is error in the console

Comment: Did you actually READ the log lines? Where is the error? I only see INFO and WARN... and all seems to be fine. That this ends up in a file that in the beginning of the line says 'SystemErr' seems a bad configuration.

Comment: @Kukeltje I see. How can I prevent it from logging under SystemErr? It was logged under SystemErr (in red) and I thought there was errors.

Comment: No idea, no Websphere user. But I remove the PF tag since it it not PF related (not Atmosphere related to)